# Number theorems on beamer in Spanish

Tags: beamer, numbering

I'm not sure if I could ask this question here, but I have to do a presentation and I want to number theorems by sections and subsections.

I have to do this in Spanish and so far, the only way I could change "Theorem" for "Teorema" is using `\newtheorem...` but that way the theorems don't get numbered properly. The theorems get assigned a number and doesn't matter which section or subsection they are part of.

Is there a way I could do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should take a look at the `ntheorem` package.

Answer (score 3):

Beamer can do all this for you:

- to number the theorem `\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]`
- to number them with the section, use the class option `envcountsect`
- to translate the theorem name use the class option `spanish` together with the `babel` package.

---

```
\documentclass[envcountsect,spanish]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\usepackage{babel}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]

\begin{document}

\section{sec}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{theorem}
        text
    \end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]